# How can I configure Cabal to build two executables?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to build [a Haskell project](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/color-word-analyzer) using Cabal. I have a file src/Main.hs which contains the module Main and a function `main`. That file runs the web interface of my app. And I have another file, src/CLI.hs which contains the module CLI and a function `main`. I can run it just fine with `runhaskell CLI ...`, but I can't seem to compile it using cabal.

The thing is, even if I specify CLI.hs as the main file (`main-is: CLI.hs`), it still compiles the project with the `main` from src/Main.hs, thereby giving me the web app instead of the CLI.

I want to be able to compile two executables, one which is the web app, and one which is the CLI, specifying the entry points of each as `main` in CLI.hs and `main` in Main.hs, respectively.

Here's the segment of the .cabal file I'm using at the moment:

```
executable color-word-analyzer-cli
  main-is:           CLI.hs
  other-modules:     AnnotateColors
                   , CategorizeColor
                   , ColorMaps
                   , FindColors
                   , PlotColors
                   , Types
                   , Main
  build-depends:       base
                     , lucid
                     ...
                     , wai-middleware-static
  hs-source-dirs:      src/
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable color-word-analyzer-web
  main-is:           Main.hs
  other-modules:     AnnotateColors
                   , CategorizeColor
                   , ColorMaps
                   , FindColors
                   , PlotColors
                   , Types
                   , CLI
  build-depends:     base
                   , lucid
                     ...
                   , wai-middleware-static
  hs-source-dirs:      src/
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Which throws the error (among others):

```
Building executable 'color-word-analyzer-cli' for color-word-analyzer-0.1.0.0..
Warning: Enabling workaround for Main module 'Main' listed in 'other-modules'
illegally!

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        Main
```

which is funny, since `Main` is clearly listed there in `other-modules`.

I'm using cabal version 3.0.0.0, and ghc version 8.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

The fully explicit form of a compilation unit is `<package>:<category>:<ident>` where in the case the packages is `color-word-analyzer`, category is `exe` and ident is the executables. So for your case you can call:

```
cabal build color-word-analyzer:exe:color-word-analyzer-cli color-word-analyzer:exe:color-word-analyzer-web
```

Now you don't actually need to specify all of that. When the executable is unique the fact that it is an executable (and not, say, a test from some other package or another package name itself) and the fact that it is from color-word-analyzer is clear in this context. You can therefore call:

```
 cabal build color-word-analyzer-cli color-word-analyzer-web
```

EDIT: because your link didn't have a stanza for `-web` I used one of my own creation which didn't include the `CLI` module. Notice your `CLI` file is `module Main` so that explains the error you see - you can't include a module `Main` as a library module.